# Cant import files, get eslint error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: ecmascript-6, cypress

I am using cypress, and I want to import a function from another file.

For some reason I cant seem to be abe to import things.

I get the error on vscode:

```
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'eslint
```

And when i run cypress i getthis error from the line:

```
import test from '../support/helperFunctions'


helperFunctions_1.default is not a function
```

I think there is no webpack on the project, I searched

Could you please tell me in which direction should i look in order to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a cypress issue. So import & export of modules are introduced with EcmaScript and by default it doesn't get supported in your JS projects.

So in order to get this work, you have to install babel, which is a transpiler(translate & compiler) and configure accordingly.

Please try to add below two dependencies in your package.json file

```
"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.8.3",
"babel-core": "6.26.3",
```

Now create .babelrc file and add the below statement which will treat modules to be imported and exported.

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

Now run your code and verify.